# Iterate JSON file into Ruby object array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, parsing

What is the best way to achieve the following?:

```
class Whatever
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :email
end
```

JSON file:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Some Name","email":"something@gmail.com"},
 {"id":"2","name":"Another Name","email":"another@gmail.com"}]
```

Now I want to read the JSON file in, parse it into an array of object `Whatever` so that `array[0]` has a `Whatever` class object with the first json object and `array[1]` would have a `Whatever` class object with the second json object.

What is the best way to achieve this in ruby?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ in ruby you should name classes starting with capital letter. Also, you must show what have you already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an all that pretty way if this is all you have for the class:

```
JSON.parse(whatevers).map do |whatever|
  element = Whatever.new
  element.id = whatever['id']
  element.name = whatever['name']
  element.email = whatever['email']
  element
end
```

---

However, if you add an index method like:

```
class Whatever
  def []=(name, value)
    instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value)
  end
end
```

It gets down to:

```
JSON.parse(whatevers, object_class: Whatever)
```

Comment: Don't forget [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) for situations like this.

Comment: in your first example, I assume the array is 'whatevers'?  inside the JSON.parse.

Comment: @GregBrethen, `whatevers` is a string, holding the json described in your question. Aka `'[{"id":"1","name":"Some Name","email":"something@gmail.com"}, {"id":"2","name":"Another Name","email":"another@gmail.com"}]'`

Comment: so then I would need to pump 'element' into an array?

Comment: @GregBrethen, not sure what you mean by *pump*. `JSON.parse` will just start iterating over the json array in the string, and for each element in the json array, it will juxtapose a `Whatever` object. Aka you ultimately just want to assign the result of the parse to a variable and it will contain the parsed array. Aka `result = JSON.parse(whatevers).map do |whatever| ...`.

Comment: Consider using `tap` in such cases to avoid redundant local variables and superfluous last `element` return.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I would still have to provide a variable name if I was to use `tap`.

Comment: ultimately I want array[0] to contain my class object with the vaule from node 1 of the json file and array[1] to contain my class object with the values from node 2 of the json file.

Comment: @GregBrethen, yes, then do the above assignment, just instead of `result = ...` do `array = ...`.